# Using playwright UI mode with Cucumber

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd, playwright, cucumberjs

Recently Playwright implemented new UI mode which could be runned with `npx playwright test --ui`
I'm using [cucumber-js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) with Playwright.
Is any way to run cucumber tests with playwright in that --ui mode?

I tried to run cucumber-js with that flag, but as expected this wasn't helpful.

Comment: How do you currently run your cucumber-js tests with playwright? Please share the code.

Comment: And what do you mean by "this was n't helpful"? Did you get any error?

Comment: Hi, Vishal! This is my pet-project https://github.com/mi4i0/playwright-cucumber-pet/tree/master/e2e

I'm trying to start it with cucumber script from package.json. I get expected error that cucumber-js don't have --ui flag

Comment: This is not possible to use UI mode with Cucumber-js runner b/c `--ui` flag is a part of Playwright runner. If you need to run BDD tests in UI mode, you can check out https://github.com/vitalets/playwright-bdd integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this config in test script:

browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });